# Какой алгоритм хеширования паролей в Linux?

Tags: linux, алгоритм, хеширование, взлом, системное-программирование

Все мы занем что в `/etc/shadow` хранится хеш sudo паролей. Если я захочу брутфоросом "подобрать" пароль с таким же хешем, то это займет много времени потому, что есть некоторая задержка по ответу в теорминал при вводе неправильного пароля. Выходит, что нужно искать другие лазейки - и первым шагом можно рассматривать алгоритм хеширования. Подскажите какой используется в linux-е и какие у него есть "особенности"(слабые места)?

Comment: Алгоритм хеширования указан в самом хеше. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/

Comment: В kali есть програмка для брутфорса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @Mike за комментарий.
Действительно, алгоритм указан в самом хеше.
Хеш имеет несколько "полей": 
пусть хеш такой  : `kaktus:$1$jbdsfj$ewryh4hferf444f3w:213:3:123:6:8:17:`

`kaktus` это имя пользователя
сам хеш `$1$jbdsfj$ewryh4hferf444f3w` - делится на несколько секторов, разделяемых `$` таким образом : `$id$salt$hashed`. Id описывает алгоритм хеширования: 
`$1$` это MD5,
`$2a$` это Blowfish,
`$2y$` это Blowfish,
`$5$` это SHA-256,
`$6$` это SHA-512,
`salt` - соль, подробнее : https://andreyex.ru/linux/kriptograficheskie-hesh-funktsii/ 
`hashed` - выходное значение хеш функции

Далее `213` это дата последнего изменения пароля (в днях с 1 января 1970 )
Далее `3` минимально допустимое кол-во дней между сменами пароля
Далее `123` максимально допустимое кол-во дней между сменами пароля(через такое кол-во дней с момента установки пароля его необходимо обязательно сменить)
Далее `6` Кол-во дней, за которое пользователь получит предупреждение о смене пароля(см. предыдущий пункт)
Далее `8` Кол-во дней, в течение которых после истечения срока действия пароля учетная запись будет отключена.
Далее `17` Дата истечения срока действия учетной записи, выраженная в количестве дней с 1 января 1970 года.

Поправьте меня, если я где-то ошибся
Источники :

- комментарий Mike
- cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file